# Отправить POST запрос НЕ из браузера и получить ответ со статус кодом 200

Tags: java

Как отправить POST запрос не из браузера и получить ответ 200?

Comment: Вы забыли написать что уже попробовали и что из этого вышло.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по метке "java" запрос надо послать из java?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
    <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Main

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject()
                .append("key", "value");

        HttpResponse<String> stringHttpResponse = Unirest.post("https://example.com")
                .body(requestBody)
                .asString();

        if (stringHttpResponse.getStatus() == 200) {
            // тут код
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.a-domain.com/foo/");

// Request parameters and other properties.
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param-1", "12345"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param-2", "Hello!"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

//Execute and get the response.
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

if (entity != null) {
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
    try {
        // do something useful
    } finally {
        instream.close();
    }
}
```

Взято [отсюда](https://overcoder.net/q/24008/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-http-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-java).